# Author-Date style with Mendeley citation manager

Tags: citations, citation-style, reference-managers

I have recently started using Mendeley Desktop with Microsoft Word. I am using the Author-Date style of citation and have encountered some difficulties. I'm hoping someone has a solution. Here are the problems I've encountered:

1. Sometimes the citation in the text includes the authors initials, while other times it does not, e.g. (L. C. Young 1987) vs (Young 1987). When I look at the citations inside Mendeley. I can't see any difference between the way they are stored. Could there be tabs or other not displayed characters?
2. If you want to use the authors name in the sentence containing the citation you might write:

> "Smith, et al. were first to discover ...."

Inserting a citation after the name comes out:

> "Smith, et al. (Smith, Jones, and Gonzales 1918) were first to discover
> ...."

Whereas, it should be:

> "Smith, et al. (1918) were first to discover ...."

Is there a way to get the correct behavior without manually modifying every citation like this, which then can no longer be updated automatically?

3. Normally, when there is two authors both names are used in the citation, while "(first author, et al. date)" is used for more than two authors. I don't get et al. until there are four or more authors. Maybe this has been standardized, but that is the way I've always done it. Is there a way to correct this behavior without getting into complicated editing of the style?
4. When I download citations, sometimes the authors initials are not followed by periods. Is there some way to add the periods without editing each entry manually?

If anyone has a solution to these problems, I'd appreciate hearing from you. Perhaps I've chosen the wrong citation manager. I am trying to avoid manual edits, since I might want to convert the document to a different citation style.

Comment: I have also requested help at Mendely, but they are MIA. I'm wondering if I could dump these into a text file and edit them with regular expressios, but I'm concerned about reimporting them back into Mendeley. Has anyone done this? If I only understood the reason for item 1. Solutions/explanations?